# Text-align right not flush

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-align

I have the text aligned right within a td. The text is aligning right but some lines are not flush against the border.

```
<td style="text-align: right;">
    <p>
        Street Address
        <br>
        State
        <br>
        Country
    </p>
</td>
```

Comment: Your line breaks are rendered as spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this quirk I put all the text on one line in the code and it worked.

```
<td style="text-align: right;">
    <p>
        Street Address<br>State<br>Country
    </p>
</td>
```